# Javafx models, работа с БД

Tags: javafx

Кто то может скинуть пример работы с бд, используя framework javafx. Или можно использовать hibernate для этого

Answer (score 1):

Технология `JavaFX` вообще не предназначена для работы с бд. Эта технология предназначенена для [RIA приложений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info).